# DynamoDB Mapper query, does it return a list or a PaginatedQueryList?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a query API where it have the list of objects returned as a response entity. On the AWS website, it shows an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#DynamoDBMapper.Methods.query) of query returning a List of objects.
However, on the DynamoDB Mapper [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#query-java.lang.Class-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-) page, it shows that it returns a PaginatedQueryList. Which one is it? Is it interchangeable? Can I use the result from the query and just return the `List<Obj>` as a response entity? Or do I have to do some conversion of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB mapper's query function return type is `PaginatedQueryList<T>`. [PaginatedQueryList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html) extends [PaginatedList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedList.html) which in turn implements the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true) interface. So, we can draw following conclusions from this

1. It's possible to cast the results of query function to List type. Implementation is provided by [PaginatedQueryList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html) class.
2. Pagination is supported as [PaginatedQueryList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html) Java docs mention following

> Paginated results are loaded on demand when the user executes an operation that requires them.

It's also possible to define a pagination strategy as well using [DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy.html).